# Unable to select the last li element within a ul using Selenium Webdriver for C#

Tags: c#, html, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I have a block of code which looks like below and I want to get to the text (inner html; **which must be 4**) of the span which is located inside the button element under the last li.

```
<ul class="xyz">
    <li class="abc">  
        <button aria-current="true" type="button">
            <span>1</span>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li class="abc">  
        <button aria-current="true" type="button">
            <span>2</span>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li class="abc">  
        <button aria-current="true" type="button">
            <span>3</span>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li class="abc">  
        <button aria-current="true" type="button">
            <span>4</span>
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When I use the following line of code I get **"no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//ul[@class='xyz']/li[last()]/button/span"}"**

```
string text= driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@class='xyz']/li[last()]/button/span")).Text;
```

Alternatively, when I use this code, I get the same error.

```
string text= driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@class='xyz']/li[last()]//button//span")).Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong XPath.
Try this

```
string text= driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//ul[@class='xyz']//li)[last()]/button/span")).Text;
```

or

```
string text= driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//ul[@class='xyz']//li)[last()]//span")).Text;
```

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions but I still get **no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector"....** error.

Comment: Maybe you are missing some wait / delay or the elements are inside iframe?